# how to binding data web component from element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component

How I can output data to attr value in my web component element? like ngmodel in angularjs

// custom element is :

```
 <custom-ele  res="value"></custom-ele>
```

Comment: Polymer({
                is: 'value',
                properties: {
                  title: String,
                  src: String
                }
              });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS only**

You could use the `attr()` CSS function combined with the `::after` CSS pseudo-class and its `content` CSS property.

```css
custom-ele::after { content: attr(res) }
```

```html
<custom-ele  res="value"></custom-ele>
```

**Custom Element definition**

You can get the attribute value in the `connectedCallback()` method and inject it in its DOM tree with a template literal variable:

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-ele', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      var res = this.getAttribute( 'res' )
      this.innerHTML = `${res}`
    }
} )
```

```html
<custom-ele  res="value"></custom-ele>
```

**Using the data-* standard notation**

You could access an element attribute by its `dataset` property if you define it using the data-* notation (i.e.: `data-res="value"` )

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-ele', class extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
          this.innerHTML = `${this.dataset.res}`
        }
    } )
```

```html
<custom-ele data-res="value"></custom-ele>
```